# How to test that messages are getting logged to console.log()?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a method that contains a `console.log()` statement. For the sake of the question, let's say that it is this:

```
$scope.logInput = function(input) {
    console.log("Input was " + input);
};
```

How can I write a unit test using Jasmine that will confirm that the console log is working? I don't see any obvious way of intercepting console data or checking the contents of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825020/how-can-i-use-jasmine-js-to-test-for-console-output